# How to find last element in an array by specific key

Tags: java, arrays, find, key

i have to find the first and the last element by a specific key (with a binary search method). I'm already done with the searchFirst method but i'm not able to complete the searchLast method. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't (it depends with value im looking for) and thats the problem.

I have a Data class with some atributes like timestamp, name, product, etc. which im reading out of a text file. When im done with filling the Data array im sorting the array with a merge sort.

Then i need the first and last element of the Array by a specific name.

The searchFirst method works perfect but the searchLast won't do what i want.

Here's the code of the searchLast method(n is the value he should look for and w isn't used at the moment).

```
public static int searchLast(Data[] array, String n, String w) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = array.length - 1;
        int m = -1;

        while (left < right) {
            m = (left + right) / 2;
            if (array[m].getName().compareTo(n) > 0) {
                right = m - 1;
            } else {
                left = m + 1;
            }
        }

        if (m >= 0) {
            if (array[right].getName().equals(n)) {
                return right;
            }
        }

        return NO_KEY;
    }
```

I can't find the bug maybe you could help me... Sometimes the code finds the last one sometimes it doesn't...

Comment: Can you give us an example of input that doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know if im allowed to post the inputarray but the getName returns a String like "GXA:name" ; x is a number and  for example im looking for a String like "G13A:Shuffle". is that enough information? - i think its the same as if i would look for the last element by specific number in an integer array.

Comment: `searchFirst` and `searchLast` gives me the idea that there maybe more than 1 repeated value in the list. and a binary search doesn't handle that case. Once it finds it, it finishes. Does it have to be a binary search?

Comment: Yea there are more than 1 vlaue with the same name.The firstSearch uses binary search and finds the right one every time so that works perfectly... can't i use binary to find the last one O.o?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int searchLast(Data[] array, String n, String w) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = array.length - 1;
        int m = -1;
        int found = -1;

            while (left < right) {
                m = (left + right) / 2;
                if (array[m].getName().compareTo(n) > 0) {
                    right = m - 1;
                } else if (array[m].getName().compareTo(n) < 0){
                    left = m + 1;
                } else {
                    found = m;
                    left = m + 1;
            }

        return found;
    }
```

Comment: That looks great thank you but it doesnt work... for first searchvalue expected 15 was 15 for 2nd expected 69 was 68 for 3rd expected 85 was 84 and so on. Your code works 2 out of 6 times... If it fails it fails by -1

Comment: got the mistake... while (left < right) must be while (left <= right)